# JQuery Dialog box doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have included in my header:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.theme.css"></script>
</head>
```

And this is in my body, I just want to test this but I'm getting an error:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    factory( jQuery );

<body>
      <script>
          $.extend({ alert: function (message, title) {
                      $("<div></div>").dialog( {
                        buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
                        close: function (event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
                        resizable: false,
                        title: title,
                        modal: true
                      }).text(message);
                    }
                });

            $.alert('message', 'fileName');
      </script>
    </body>
```

I'm not sure why dialog box doesn't work in my code. Am I missing something in my script or something else is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the jQuery UI script after the jQuery script, you need them both like this (because jQuery UI uses jQuery and therefore jQuery needs to be loaded first)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.theme.css"></script>
</head>
```

Please note to use the version of the script you have, "jquery-3.1.1.js" is just an example.

I told you in a comment that you don't need two of jQuery script - the regular and minified, not to remove them both. So to sum things up

1. jQuery = jQuery-min
2. jQuery != jQuery-UI
3. jQuery-UI needs jQuery to be loaded first.

Comment: where I can download UI script and which version?

Comment: One more thing, why would you include both regular and minified version of jQuery script? Remove one.

Comment: What should be included from the zip file that I can download on the JQuery website?

Comment: include jquery-ui.js and all the .css files

Comment: No problem. See my edit, you should include the CSS files too.

Comment: I updated my question, now I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
factory( jQuery );